# Update child componet in Appcomponent in angular

Tags: angular

In my application header footer and sidebar is common and middle content will changing dynamically.In side bar I have more hyperlinks it will update middle content dynamically .Some scenarion I want to  hide sidebar and footer .Can anybody tell how to do?

```
<app-header> <app-header>
<div>
  <app-sidebar> <app-sidebar>
  <app-font> <app-font>
</div>
<app-footer> <app-footer>
```

Thanks

Comment: The code you've attached is invalid HTML - the tags should have closing tags as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use *ngIf angular directive.
Also include your child component selector in your template.

Comment: I have five link if user click table or font i need to hide footer and sidebar and if user click text or color need to show  footer and sidebar

Answer (score 0):

There are several way for you to hide an element in angular:

---

You can use `*ngIf`:

```
<app-header *ngIf="shouldVisible"> <app-header>
...
<app-footer *ngIf="shouldVisible"> <app-footer>
```

In your app.component.ts (I assumming you are placing those selector inside app component )

```
//Change shouldVisible when you need to
shouldVisible = true;
```

---

Or passing css classes using [`ngClass`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass) to that component, this way you have more control in styling that component dynamically:

```
<app-header [ngClass]="yourClasses"> <app-header>
...
<app-footer [ngClass]="yourClasses"> <app-footer>
```

```
//You ca manipulate the class you wish to pass in
yourClasses = ['none']
```

And inside your header and footer component style, declare those style

```
:host.none {
 display: none;
 /*Or what ever style you want*/
}
```